# understanding 'Output of the function must be the same size as the input. If FUN is an array-valued integrand, set the 'ArrayValued' option to true'

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to numerically integrate my function `log(1+A.*exp(-t.^2))` from -Inf to Inf where `A` is a 80x1 matrix. When I used the integral function, it shows error that

> Output of the function must be the same size as the input. If FUN is an array-valued integrand, set the 'ArrayValued' option to true

```
yprime = integral( @(t) (log(1+ A.*exp(-t.^2))),-Inf,Inf );
```

I expected a `yprime` matrix of 80x1, but it doesn't!

Comment: Since your function is array-valued, you should do as the error message says.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just do as the error message suggests. When Matlab tells you to set a named option for a function, that means to supply the option name and the value for it as trailing arguments to the function.

```
>> yprime = integral( @(t) (log(1+ A.*exp(-t.^2))), -Inf, Inf, 'ArrayValued', true );
>> size(yprime)
ans =
    80     1
```